# Use cases for combining OctoberCMS together with Vue.js

Tags: vue.js, octobercms

when browsing the web I saw that some people are using OctoberCMS together with Vue.js. I'm wondering what would be the use cases/advantages for combining the 2 of them instead of only using OctoberCMS. What can be done better with the combination?
Or do people just combine the 2 of them because they are already used to Vue.js?

One point I read was that with the combination of the 2 it is possible to create SinglePageApps. Doesn't provide OctoberCMS itself already themes for SinglePageApps?

Thanks in advance

Comment: You would use this in cases where you need more (or full) control of your frontend. While there are existing themes and some of them are SPA, sometimes you could spend more time customizing those themes than just implementing what you need with vue from scratch. Themes could come with more stuff than you need, they could be coded in a way that it's hard to customize, etc

Comment: They are two completely different frameworks that do different things. OctoberCMS is a CMS that allows users to interact with flat file data or database data. Vuejs is a progressive framework for building user interfaces.